# Gerund at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

I just noticed a sentence in [an academic paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D7770511208976C85AB4B6336C5E7CEC/S2398772318000223a.pdf/mapping_global_migration_law_or_the_two_batavias.pdf) which says:

> This symposium has marshaled numerous insights regarding the emergence of a general field of inquiry within international law on the movement of people. **To move** into this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance of the conventional wisdom that questions of migration are within the purview of the sovereign state, and a matter of sovereign territorial prerogative.

But, this structure sounds somewhat weird to my non-native ears. If I wanted to write this sentence, I would start by "**moving**", not "to move".

Anyway, is the original sentence grammatically correct? (if yes, why?) What about starting with "moving"?

Comment: I agree the gerund sounds better, but I don't think the infinitive is *wrong*.  It's just inelegant.  Then again, the entire sentence is overly *wordy* and could use the red pencil of a qualified editor.

Comment: "To move," "Moving," and "Movement" would all work. I would also tighten up this sentence, but it's not grammatically wrong as is.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you ... I was really struggling with this complex sentence, and I thought there is something wrong with my (limited) English knowledge so that I can't understand it.

Comment: @Chemomechanics If we use "to move" at the beginning, what would be the subject of "has required"? or in that case, doesn't the "has required" need to be passive and be transferred to the end?

Comment: Each of the replacements is the subject of "has required." Infinitives, gerunds, and nouns can all be subjects.

Comment: @OmidRezaAbbasi  It's an *unnecessarily* complex sentence.  I could probably cut it in half and still retain the meaning.

Comment: I think the reason it sounds "off" is because "move" does not license (specifically permit) an infinitival clause as subject. To my ear, the gerund-participial clause "Moving into this conceptual terrain" sounds better, probably because such clauses have certain similarities with nouns.

Comment: @OmidRezaAbbasi Use "To move . . . requires"—and only if it has not happened yet. If you change it to "Moving" (which you should certainly do if it has already happened) then use either "required" or "requires," depending on if it has already happened or not.

Comment: The original sentence is completely grammatically correct. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I would change the main word: "move". It is not appropriately used here, as far as I understand the text. Infinitives, gerunds, nouns, are all usable.

I would use:

> **The transition** into this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...

or:

> **To walk** into this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...

or:

> **To enter** (into) this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...

or their gerund counterparts:

> - **Transitioning** into this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...
> - **Walking** into this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...
> - **Entering** (into) this conceptual terrain has required a certain amount of defiance ...

However, overall, I prefer the non-gerund variants in this particular case.

Comment: I agree with you on the first replacement, which is "transition". However, it doesn't answer my question. The question remains unchanged as, again, wouldn't it better to write "Walking into ..." or "Entering this ..."?

Comment: One can move into terrain: there is nothing wrong with it. There is no need to replace it with a gerund. Had the author wanted that, s/he would have used it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.  We can use to + infinitive as a subject.  But your ears caught the fact that to + infinitive is much less common than using a gerund.

We could also use a gerund in the case you mentioned.

However, we more often use to + infinitive after an empty subject.  For example,

> It was a terrible mistake **to leave** New Zealand.